# Deregistered from Germany and Returned

Tags: germany, resident-permit, residence-cards

I used to study in Germany and graduated recently. According to [§ 16 AufenthG](https://web.archive.org/web/20150402112558/http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0187) I have the right to work/reside for 18 months afterwards in Germany.

When I was leaving the country I deregistered (*Abmeldung*) from the city that I was residing in. Just three months after my deregistration I returned to Germany.

At the *Bürgeramt* I have been told that since I have deregistered I cannot ask for prolonged stay in Germany anymore.

Since the woman I was talking to seems to discriminate her clients I was wondering whether there is a law that states that after deregistration one cannot extend his/her residence permit.

Comment: Did they "touch" your visa or other *Aufenthaltsgenehmigung* while you deregistered, or did you simply announce that your current address will no longer be valid (as you might do when simply moving to a different city within Germany)?

Comment: No but in my abmeldung paper it is written that I am leaving to Canada. In any case I was back in less than 6 months: well actually less than 3 months!

Comment: Maybe someone will be able to give some feedback but I am afraid that this is getting a bit too technical and specialized to rely on amateur interpretations of the law. Since, based on your other questions, the stakes seem pretty high and your schedule is tight, it might be worth seeking help from a legal professional or maybe some migrant support organization, if you can find one (unfortunately, I can't really suggest any for Germany).

Comment: i am facing same problem i de-registered and came back into germany now they telling me to go back . i dont know what to do now, did you find any solution? can you help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For later reference, I have asked the question from two different  Ausländerbehörde in Germany. The person only can rely on this law if has not de-registered from Germany to leave it. In that case he has to leave the Germany and apply for job-seeking visa through a consulate. This rules have exception for countries like, US, South Korea and a few more; I think they don't need a Schengen visa to be in Germany anyway!

Comment: Deregistration and leaving is **not temporary in nature**, so the residence permit becomes invalid when you leave Germany. It doesn't matter that you later change your mind and return 3 months later. The 6 month rule is is for cases where you temporarily leave but don't return within 6 months. [§51 Termination of lawful residence; continued validity of restrictions](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p1050) *(1) The residence title expires : ... 6. if the foreigner leaves the federal territory for a reason which is **not temporary in nature,***